# Displaying Terms And Conditions page on opening Fiori launchpad

Tags: sap-fiori

I want to display Terms and Conditions Page for the user who sign in first time before redirecting to the Fiori launchpad. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see if an extension would suit your use case, as seen here in the footer bar image in the documentation: [Extending the Launchpad](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/7.52.0/en-US/56e9328978954c77946b75c0976f221c.html).

Otherwise, it might be possible to implement this feature using an FLP plugin.
Helpful additional info can be found here:

- FLP Extension points APIs: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Renderer
- UShell services: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ushell.services